# Find a positive semi-definite matrix $Q\in\mathbb{C}^{2\mathrm{x}2}$ so that $QQ=P$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm currently studying for my linear algebra exam by doing old exams. I already solved this question but I think my way is too complex (and requires a calculator or a lot of time). Therefore, I would like to know if there is an easier way to solve this.

**The question:**

Let $P=\begin{bmatrix}
73&-36\\
-36&52
\end{bmatrix}$.

Find a positive-definite matrix $Q\in\mathbb{C}^{2\mathrm{x}2}$, so that $QQ=P$.

**My solution:**

Let $Q=\begin{bmatrix}
a&b\\
c&d
\end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb{C}^{2\mathrm{x}2}$.

Then
$QQ=\begin{bmatrix}
a^2+bc&ab+bd\\
ac+dc&bc+d^2
\end{bmatrix}$

We get

$\begin{cases}
a^2+bc=73&\\
bc+d^2=52&\\
ac+dc=-36&\\
ab+bd=-36&
\end{cases}$

With a calculator we get 4 different answers, and by testing with a calculator which answer is a positive semi-definite matrix (eigenvalues are $\ge0$) we get that
$Q=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{41}{5}&-\frac{12}{5}\\
-\frac{12}{5}&\frac{34}{5}
\end{bmatrix}.$

**Edit**: Fixed the wrong b and c in the final answer.

**Edit 2**: Changed positive matrix to positive semi-definite matrix.

Comment: "I think my way is too complex". That can be changed easily - consider $Q\in \Bbb R^{2\times 2}$.

Comment: $P$ is symmetric. Diagonalize $P=ADA^{-1}$ and take the square root of $D$.

Comment: not sure what is "positive matrix". do you mean "positive semidefinite"?

Comment: @cineel Oh yes, you are correct. I'm sorry about that. My native language isn't English. Thanks for noticing the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is fine. The other way is to diagonalise the matrix, which is possible because your matrix is symmetric, and then to take the square roots of the eigenvalues.
If $P = {}^tU \pmatrix{\lambda_1 & 0 \cr 0 &\lambda_2} U$, with $U$ orthogonal,  then $Q = {}^tU \pmatrix{\sqrt{\lambda_1} & 0 \cr 0 & \sqrt{\lambda_2}} U$ satisfies $Q^2=P$.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, guess that $Q=\alpha P + \beta I$ and find $\alpha$ and $\beta$ using the characteristic polynomial $P^2-125P +2500=0$.

Answer (score 0):

***HINT***

Notice that $ac+cd=ab+bd\Rightarrow a(c-b)=d(b-c)\Rightarrow a(c-b)=-d(c-b)\Rightarrow$ if $c\neq b\Rightarrow a=-d$